# DataTable export table data with image (PDF,Excel and csv)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatable

I have a image column in my data table which I'm trying to export to PDF, CSV and Excel. It exports the table data without the image. When I open the exported file, the image column is just showing an empty record.

```js
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "bFilter": false,
  "bInfo": false,
  "order": [],
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: 'no-sort',
    orderable: false
  }],
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    exportOptions: {
      stripHtml: false,
      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }
  }, {
    extend: 'excel',
    text: 'Excel',
    exportOptions: {
      stripHtml: false,
      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }
  }, {
    extend: 'csv',
    extend: 'csvHtml5',
    text: 'CSV',
    exportOptions: {
      stripHtml: false,
      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }
  }]
})
```

[image]

Comment: This may hold your answer: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41096/export-image-in-printing. Although I'm not certain how you're expecting to export an image to a CSV file - URL/path, perhaps?